# How to properly delete a MySQL table in c#?

Tags: c#, mysql

I want to run a query in c#

```
delete from dials
```

Are there any suitable libraries that can help me run this query in c# windows form Application?

Comment: You want to delete a table? Or delete the data in the cable? There's quite a bit difference.

Comment: I Only want to delete the data from table

Comment: See also `TRUNCATE TABLE dials`. It will reset auto increment columns but requires higher privileges.

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11103338/4685428) answer

Comment: Please re-read my answer :) , Hope it helps :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect to MySQL Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21618015/how-to-connect-to-mysql-database)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("DELETE  from [tablenamehere] where Somethingunique=@unique",connectionstring)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@unique", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = somethinguniqueHere;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: [Don't use AddWithValue() for code examples](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). It leads to people using it in programs without knowing potential performance damage they are doing.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn , i am sorry ... i always use and suggest `Add` instead of `Add with value..You can check my other answers such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49596131/vb-net-how-to-add-a-value-number-in-my-form-with-a-value-number-in-my-database-a/49597366#49597366) ... I edited my qs now and now it's perfect :)