# vb.net how to add a value number in my form with a value number in my database and update as a new data

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

```
Private Sub btnpay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnpay.Click
    Dim sql1 As String
    sql1 = "UPDATE GuestDetil SET OutStandingFee=@outstanding,TotalAmount=@totalamount,TotalPaid=@totalpaid WHERE ICNumber=@icnum"
    conn1 = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Sparrow's Resort Database.accdb; Persist Security Info=False;")
    conn1.Open()
    cmd1 = New OleDbCommand(sql1, conn1)
    cmd1.CommandText = sql1
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@outstanding", lblnewoutstanding.Text)
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@totalamount", Val(lbltotalamount.Text) + Val("@totalamount"))
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@totalpaid", Val(lbldeposit.Text) + Val("@totalpaid"))
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@icum", lblIC.Text)
    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
    conn1.Close()

    Me.Close()

End Sub
```

this is my code I'm trying to add the 2 number which is Val(lbltotalamount.Text) and Val(lbldeposit.Text) with the old data in my database and update as a new data but now my code is not working ,the data will only insert the new number and without adding the old number in my database.
someone  help me please!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly , never-ever use `AddWithValue` .. At points, it may not cause errors/may not conflict with data but in most cases it'll corrupt the data.The reason is that , it infers the database type to query parameter.

[Read more here](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Moving on to your next issue,you want to **UPDATE** the table with a value that exists in the table.It is not an issue unless you really retrieve the data from the table first and then use it again to update the table.

Currently you are using an `Update` statement/query which doesn't return/retrieve values from your table/database.

You , in this case, can use a `Select` statement :

```
Select * from tableName
```

But you want a `WHERE` condition as well(depending on your post/requirement)

```
Select * from tableName WHERE ColumnForCondition=@columnValue
```

I guess you know how to deal with the `@columnValue` parameter.

Then you can go with 2 options to read the data.

1 . You can use a datatable.This is only necessary if u wish to do something with the table later or else it is just a waste of time and threat for performance.

2. You can use a dataReader which is way faster than a datatable.I will show example of both :

   **DATATABLE**

   ```
   Dim cmd as New OleDbCommand("Use the select statement stated above",connection)
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@paramName" , OledbType.VarChar).Value = ValueHere
   Dim dt as New DataTable
   Dim ada as New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
   ada.Fill(dt)
   ```

**Get value from datatable**

```
  Dim value1 = table(0)(1).ToString ' Here 0 is the row count and 1 is the column count .. tho row count doesn't matter as your select statement will return only one row
```

**DataReader**

```
  'use OleDbCommand as same as i used in the DATATABLE section

  Dim dr as DataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

  dr.Read()

  Dim Value1 = dr(0).ToString
```

Then you can go with your update statement as follows :

```
  Dim cmd As New OledbCommand(""UPDATE GuestDetil SET OutStandingFee=@outstanding,TotalAmount=@totalamount,TotalPaid=@totalpaid WHERE ICNumber=@icnum", connection)

  cmd.Parameters.Add("@outstanding" , OledbType.Varchar).Value = yourValue + value1

  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Hope this helps to enrich your knowledge :)

Comment: sorry I'm not really know about the meanning of cmd.Parameters.Add("@outstanding" , OledbType.Varchar).Value = yourValue + value1 this line what's the yourValue and value1 ? because one of the value are inside the database

Comment: youvalue in this case could be `lblnewoutstanding.Text` and `value1` is the column value retrieved from the database(according to ur post, it could be `@totalamount` ) ... and dont forget to mark it as answer if it helped

Comment: value1 cannot be @totalamount because I cant dim something that bring @ like this line Dim Value1 = dr(0).ToString

Comment: why not ?? just use `Dim Value1 = dr(0).ToString` and replace 0 with the column number u want ...